# como hacer paginacion con ajax en laravel

Tags: laravel, ajax

pude haber usado datatables pero lo hago con fines de aprender y personalizar mi propia tabla.

he listado mi base de datos mediante ajax y le puse un buscador igual con ajax me busca de manera normal me lista tambien, pero he intentado hacer la paginacion con ajax y no encuentro algo que me ayude con esto o alguna guia o de que manera podria hacerlo

si alguien puede ayudarme le agradeceria de corazoncito

bien mi controllador

```
 public function consulta(Request $request)
 {
    if($request->ajax()) {

        $input=$request->input('pasoAConsulta');

        $medicamento = Medicamento::orderBy('id', 'Asc')->
            where("denominacion_comercial", "like","%$input%")
            ->orWhere("laboratorio", "like", "%$input%")->take(5)->paginate(5);

        return response()->json($medicamento);
    }
}
```

mi js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(obtener_datos());  
    $('#busqueda').on('keyup',function (){
        var valorBusquado = $(this).val();     
        if (valorBusquado!="") {
            obtener_datos(valorBusquado);
        }
        else {
            obtener_datos();  
        }
    });

    function obtener_datos(valorBusquado) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url : '{{route('busque')}}',
            type : 'get',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : { pasoAConsulta: valorBusquado }, 
        }).done(function(resultado)
        {console.log(resultado);
                    let body = document.querySelector('#unbody');  


                    body.innerHTML = ''; 
                    for (let item of resultado.data) {

                        body.innerHTML +=`

                        <tr>
                             <td>${item.denominacion_comercial}</td>
                             <td>${item.denominacion_generica}</td>
                             <td>${item.presentacion}</td>
                             <td>${item.precio}</td>
                             <td>${item.laboratorio}</td>
                             <td>${item.ubicacion}</td>
                             <td>${item.vencimiento}</td>
                        </tr>

                           `
                    }


        })
    }
});
```

mi ruta

```
 Route::get('busque','VentasController@consulta')->name('busque');
```

mi vista

```
    <br><br>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" >
    <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: black">DENOMINACION C.</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: black">DENOMINACION G.</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: black">PRESENTACIÓN </th>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: black">PRECIO </th>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: black">STOCK</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: black">LABORATORIO</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: black">UBICACIÓN C.</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: black">VENCIMIENTO</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;color: black">OPCIONES</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="unbody">

        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>
```

Comment: la parte del código de tu vista Blade donde llamas a la páginacion como la estas realizando?, tampoco creo que estés usando datatables...

Comment: para eso lo habia añadido esto  
----------
 <div id="paginate"></div>------

----
y en el js tenias esto  ---------


 let pag =document.querySelector('#paginate'); 

                pag.innerHTML = '';

                pag.innerHTML ="<a>${resultado->render]</a>"

-------pero lo borre no creo que sea buena idea

Comment: El detalle es que para poder "saltar" de página en página, necesitas una botonera para ir a la siguiente página o alguna es específico, sin ello no se me ocurre de otra forma.